# ignore parent tag of array elements xml tag JAXBContext

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I want to unmarshal a complex object using JAXBContext.

The object contains arrays, each element starts with  tag.

The xml file is like:

```
<root>
  <name>any name</name>
  ..
  <movies>
    <element>
        <id>123</id>
        <name>transformers</name>
    </element>
    <element>
        <id>567</id>
        <name>joker</name>
    </element>
    ...
  </movies>
</root>
```

My pojo is :

```
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
public class Personalization {
 private String name;
 ..
 private Movie[] movies;
}

public class Movie{
 private String id;
 private String name;
}
```

When i tried to do the mapping, the movies array contains null.
When i removed the  tags it worked.
I have to keep the xml as it is because it is require to be in that format.
How to ignore the  tag in each movie element?

Note: I can't create Element class & embed the movie attributes there, because i need to map the same pojo to json formatted file below :

```
{
  "name":any name,
  ..
  'movies": [
        {
        "id": 123,
        "name:"transformers
        },
        {
        "id":567,
        "name":joker
         
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some annotations on the movie list, first of all your list is "wrapped": you have a containing "movies" element on the sequence of "element", and jaxb has to know that each list element is named "element", so it would look like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
public class Personalization {
 private String name;
 ..
 @XmlElementWrapper(name="movies")
 @XmlElement(name ="element")
 private Movie[] movies;
}

public class Movie{
 private String id;
 private String name;
}
```

Comment: I set the annotations on the getter & it worked! thanks.